# What is the drop shadow filter for snapshots on Mac OSX?

Tags: drop-shadow

If someone was to match the drop shadow settings OSX adds to snapshots what would the CSS settings be?

For example, here's a blank image:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a CSS coding question rather than a graphic design question - but anyway there's an answer here which might help you from Stack Overflow: [Drop shadow for PNG images in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186688/drop-shadow-for-png-image-in-css/12921987#12921987)

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for helping anyway. You win the Help Anyway trophy I just invented. I wasn't sure where to ask. I thought if I ask on Stack Overflow they will tell me it's a graphic design question and if I ask on Graphic Design they will tell me it's a Stack Overflow lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this thread - you might find it helps a lot.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73849/mac-os-x-10-7-window-shadow-params